# Get IP Address of Remote Device listening to a Port

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I'm working with a remote device that accepts JSON string commands and gives a response based upon which one of the 25 JSON inputs it receives. The remote device is on my LAN and one of the commands, `getIpConfig`, returns the IP of the remote device assigned by my router (DHCP).

Currently, I only know how to communicate with the remote device through a Socket. Below is the code I'm using once I know the IP address of the master

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

IPAddress masterIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.104");

int port = 8784;

IPEndPoint masterEP = new IPEndPoint(masterIP, port);

s.Connect(masterEP);
Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}.", s.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

try
{
    string command = Command(Commands.getIpConfig.ToString());

    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

    //Block until send returns
    int bytesSent = s.Send(msg, SocketFlags.None);

    Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to {1}.", bytesSent, s.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

    //Get reply from the master anchor
    int bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes, SocketFlags.None);
    string returnValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    GetIpConfig ipConfig = new GetIpConfig();
    ipConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetIpConfig>(returnValue);

    Console.WriteLine("IP Address of the Master is: {0}", ipConfig.ip.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now this only works if I know the IP address of the remote device. The IP changes, as is typical for DHCP.

My question is, since this remote device is always listening to Port 8784, is there anyway to send a packet of data to this port, the `getIpConfig` JSON command and listen for a response? Once I get that response, the Remote Device will tell me what IP it is on in JSON. I can then deserialize that and use my code above to execute more commands through the connected Socket.

This is my first time, so I'm sorry if I didn't do everything right. I'm new to C# and programming in general.

Comment: If your device supports some form of discovery protocol (bonjour, WSSD,...) you should use that protocol to find communication partners. If it does not support any discovery protocol, you are in for some hacking or you configure your DHCP server (router) to assign same IP address to the same MAC address all the time.

Comment: Ah, okay. I read about bonjour and understand the current issue with DHCP. It's almost sad this isn't as easy as it could be. Thanks for the response.